# Assigning Strings to an Integer in Dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to assign a string to an integer in a dictionary, but I get an error.

This is my code:

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary[0] = 0
dictionary[0]['name'] = 'John'
```

This is the error I get:

```
dictionary[0]['name'] = 'John'
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

How do I assign a string to an integer?

Comment: *"How do I assign a string to an integer?"* What on earth does that mean?

Comment: you are trying to assign value to a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
dd = {}
dd[0] = 0
dd[0] = {'name':'John'}
```

Out: {0: {'name': 'John'}}

Answer (score 0):

This code `dictionary[0] = 0` is assigning the key `0` to the value `0`. If you want a multi-level dictionary, you need to actually assign the `0` key to another dictionary.

You'd need something like this:

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary[0] = {}
dictionary[0]['name'] = 'John'
```

That gets you something that works, but it sounds like you actually maybe want a list of dictionaries. Something like this:

```
user_list = []
user_list[0] = {}
user_list[0]['name'] = 'John'
```

Having that many lines to initialize a single thing is discouraged in python as well, so the final code should be something like this:

```
user_list = [{'name': 'John'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did `dictionary[0] = 0` and then tried `dictionary[0]['name'] = 'John'`. But the element `dictionary[0]` is not a dictionary so you cannot access the element with key `name`. First you have to create the dictionary to be assigned to the element with key `0`:

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary[0] = {}
dictionary[0]['name'] = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix different things and using a 1d dictionary as 2d. A solution could be the creation of a list of dictionaries:

```
l_dic = []
l_dic.append([0,{}])
l[0][1]['name'] = 'John'
```

In this way you can continue adding element like:

```
l_dic[0][1]['surname'] = 'Wayne'
l_dic.append([123,{}])
l_dic[1][1]['name'] = 'Tom
l_dic[1][1]['surname'] = 'Inks'
```

and so on... you got my point. 
The integer associated to 'John' is:

```
print l_dic[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a built-in dictionary *subclass* [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which will make each entry in the dictionary another dictionary which will create entries within the outer one automatically:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(dict)
dictionary[0]['name'] = 'John'
dictionary[1]['name'] = 'Paul'
dictionary[2]['name'] = 'George'
# ... etc
```